# Wrong date on api fixer io for exchange

Tags: api, fixer.io

I use on my website an api for exchange from [api fixer io](http://fixer.io/) but it gives me the exchange from yesterday! My code is 
`$content = file_get_contents("http://api.fixer.io/latest");
$content = json_decode($content, TRUE);`

Did anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange Rates aren't updating on weekend and if you are making an API request, it will show the latest exchange rates